# Let $f: [0,\infty) \to \mathbb R$ be a $\lambda$-integrable function such that $\int_{[0,t]} f\,d\lambda =0$ for all $t\ge 0$. Prove that $f=0$ a.e.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification, lebesgue-integral

this is an exercise that I find. I'd like to know if the following is correct.

> Let $f: [0,\infty) \to \mathbb R$ be a $\lambda$-integrable function such that $\int_{[0,t]} f\,d\lambda =0$ for all $t\ge 0$. Prove that $f=0$ a.e.

Let $\mathscr A = \{ A\subset [0,\infty): \int_A f \, d\lambda =0\}$. By the dominated convergence thm it follows that $[0,\infty)\in \mathscr A$. If $A, B\in \mathscr A$,  and $A\subset B$ then $0=\int_B f \, d\lambda = \int_A f \, d\lambda + \int_{B-A} f \, d\lambda=0+\int_{A^c} f \, d\lambda$, so $B-A\in \mathscr A$. Now let an increasing sequence $\{A_n\}\subset \mathscr A$, that is $A_n\uparrow A$  where $A=\bigcup A_n$. Since $\lim_n \chi _{A_n}= \chi_A$, then $f\chi_{A_n}\to f\chi_A$ a.e., using the fact that $f$ is in $\mathscr L^1$ and dominates the sequence and the limit, by the dominated convergence thm it follows that

\begin{align*}\int_A f \, d\lambda = \int f\chi_A \, d\lambda &=\lim_n\int f \chi_{A_n} \, d\lambda\\
&=\lim_n\int_{A_n} f \, d\lambda\\
&=0\end{align*}

$A\in \mathscr A$.  Then $\mathscr A$ is a Dynkin system. Now since $\mathscr A$ contains the class $\mathcal C=\{[0,t]: t\ge 0\}$ by hypothesis and this is a $\pi$-system, hence contains $\sigma (\{[0,t]: t\ge 0\})=\mathscr B ([0,\infty))$ (Borel sigma algebra).

Now let $\epsilon>0$ and let $A=\{f>\epsilon\}$ and $B=\{f<-\epsilon\}$, then $f\chi_A>\epsilon \chi_A$, so $0=\int_A f \, d\lambda\ge \epsilon \lambda(A)$ and $f\chi_ B<-\epsilon \chi_B$ so $\epsilon \lambda(B)\le -\int_B f \, d\lambda=0$ implies that $\lambda(A)=\lambda(B)=0$. Since

$$\{|f|>0\}=\{f<0\}\cup \{f>0\}=\bigcup_n \{f< -1/n\}\cup \bigcup_n \{f>1/n\}$$

Then $f=0$ a.e. as was to be shown

Comment: Your family $\mathscr A$ also contains all sets of Lebesgue measure zero.  From that you can conclude that $\mathscr A$ contains all measurable sets, not merely all Borel sets.  You need that, don't you, for your sets $A$ and $B$ in the last paragraph?  [I assume that the exercise doesn't allow an appeal to the Lebesgue differentiation theorem however, since that would give a much lazier proof?]

Comment: @B.S.Thomson But $f$ is measurable and for instance $A$ and $B$ in the last part are Borel sets; honestly the exercise doesn't give us an structure in $[0,\infty)$ and I suppose that is the sigma algebra of Borel sets.

Comment: Don't follow.  If $f$ is measurable then you can claim that $\{x:f(x)>\epsilon\}$ is a measurable set.  It might not be a Borel set.  You were given only that $f$ is integrable (hence of course measurable).

Comment: Dear @B.S.Thomson There is way to know in the exercise as stated what sigma algebra we have on $[0,\infty)$, if the sigma algebra is the Borel sigma algebra therefore $f^{-1} ((\epsilon, \infty))\in \mathscr B ([0,\infty))$.

Comment: Your problem states that "$f$ is a $\lambda$-integrable function" on $[0,\infty)$.  I took that to mean that we are talking Lebesgue measure and Lebesgue integral.  Did you intend $\lambda$ just to be an arbitrary measure defined on the Borel sets?   If so can you edit the problem accordingly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things which you have to be careful about:

Instead of $\mathscr{A} = \{A \subseteq [0,\infty) \mid \int_A f \,\text{d}\lambda = 0\}$ you want
$$
\mathscr{A}
 = \left\{ A \in \mathscr{B}([0,\infty))
     \,\middle|\, \int_A f \,\text{d}\lambda = 0 \right\}
$$
so that the integral makes sense.

My main problem with your proof is that you need to explain why it follows from $[0,t] \in \mathscr{A}$ for every $t \geq 0$ that $\mathscr{B}([0,\infty)) \subseteq \mathscr{A}$. Notice that you haven’t shown that $\mathscr{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, but only that it is a Dynkin system, because you only deal with disjoint intervalls.

The rest of the proof looks good to me.

Comment: Dear @JendrikStelzner thank you for your comments I'd appreciate it. The set $\mathscr A$ is a Dynkin class and the class  $\mathcal C$ of closed intervals $[0,t] $ for all $t\ge 0$ forms a $\pi$-system, therefore $d (\mathcal C)=\sigma (\mathcal C)\subset \mathscr A$ doesn't? (where $d(\cdot)$ the dynkin class generated by $(\cdot)$)

Comment: Yes, this works.

Comment: @JendrikSteizner adding this explanation in the proof, do you think that the proof is correct?

Comment: As far as I can tell the proof is then correct.